# ColdFusion Automatic Timing Script w/ Conditionals

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I need some help with creating an automatic timing script with ColdFusion. My assumption is cfschedule and conditionals will be used to get this done. I am looking for something automatic, not on browser loads.

Anyways, every 60 minutes I would like to see if a page on one of my servers (http://www.mysite.com/page.php) is working or not.

If the page is down when it is checked, then it will check again in 5 minutes to see if the page is back up.

If it is not back up, then I am sent an e-mail to email@mysite.com. If it is back up, then no action is required and we start the 60 minute cycle check again.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: This isn't a CF based solution, but I ran across this the other day, should met your needs: http://www.labnol.org/internet/website-uptime-monitor/21060/ Because it's outside your server, I think you're better off, as if a page isn't working, your whole server may not be.

Comment: I use this service and am happy with it:  http://siteuptime.com/  Free for 3 sites or services (https/s, SMTP)

Comment: the script is for a server behind a firewall that those services will not be helpful, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Mike,

Not sure what version of CFML you are on but you could certainly set a scheduled task in your cf-administrator (I prefer the admin over cfschedule ... personal preference is all) to run your "site checker" script/page each hour and then, in that script/page, you could do something along the lines of:

```
<cfhttp url="http://mysite.com/ping-this-mofo.cfm" method="get" >
<cfif cfhttp.statusCode neq "200 OK">
    <!--- some code to sleep for 5 minutes or a one-time cfschedule to check the site again --->
    <cfschedule action="run" task="my-task-thingy" url="script-that-will-run" interval="once" startDate="today" startTime="5 minutes from now" />
</cfif>
```

Then, when that "sub-scheduled task" runs, you could check for the server being active and, if it isn't, fire off a an email via cfmail.

Comment: thx but that is not what I need. I need a script that checks every 60 minutes and if the page I'm checking is down then check again in 5 minutes. the code only checks once, not twice.